# How to handle a delete trigger on two related tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say you have two tables, table a and table b.  And assume that table a has a foreign key constraint referencing table_b_id to ensure that a record exists in table b before being added to table a.

I want to setup a trigger so if you delete EITHER table a or table b, the associated record is deleted in the other table.

I can create an AFTER DELETE trigger for table a, which has the foreign key constraint, to delete the associated record in table b no problem.

HOWEVER, if I try to do a BEFORE or AFTER trigger on table b, it fails:

- Doing a before trigger will cause it to delete the record in table a, which then triggers the delete of the record on table b im in the middle of deleting so I get a:
  `ERROR:  tuple to be deleted was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command` error.  If I return NULL in the before trigger function than the record in table a is deleted by not in table b.
- Doing an after trigger fails due to the foreign key constraint.

How do you handle a circular situation like this to ensure that if either are deleted the other is removed?  Here's some code to demo what Im talking about:

```
CREATE TABLE b
( 
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE a
( 
  id SERIAL,  
  b_id integer, 
  name text,
  constraint fk_b_id
     foreign key (b_id) 
     REFERENCES b (id)
);
```

Before Trigger on A:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trgfunc_delete_b_before_a()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  COST 100
  VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
  AS $BODY$
  DECLARE _b_id_to_delete integer;
    BEGIN
        _b_id_to_delete = OLD.b_id;
        DELETE FROM b WHERE id = _b_id_to_delete;
        RETURN OLD;
    END;
  $BODY$;

  CREATE TRIGGER trg_delete_b_before_a
    BEFORE DELETE
    ON a
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trgfunc_delete_b_before_a();
```

AFTER TRIGGER VERSION on B

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trgfunc_delete_a_after_b()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  COST 100
  VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
  AS $BODY$
  DECLARE _b_id_to_delete integer;
    BEGIN
        _b_id_to_delete = OLD.id;
        DELETE FROM a WHERE b_id = _b_id_to_delete;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
  $BODY$;

  CREATE TRIGGER trg_delete_a_after_b
    AFTER DELETE
    ON b
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trgfunc_delete_a_after_b();
```

BEFORE TRIGGER VERSION on B

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trgfunc_delete_a_before_b()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  COST 100
  VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
  AS $BODY$
  DECLARE _b_id_to_delete integer;
    BEGIN
        _b_id_to_delete = OLD.id;
        DELETE FROM a WHERE b_id = _b_id_to_delete;
        RETURN OLD;
    END;
  $BODY$;

  CREATE TRIGGER trg_delete_a_before_b
    BEFORE DELETE
    ON b
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trgfunc_delete_a_before_b();
```

THEN

```
insert into b (name) values ('b test');
insert into a (b_id, name) values (1, 'a test');
```

Then delete from b works as its the foreign key:

```
delete from b;
DELETE 1
select * from b;
 id | name
----+------
(0 rows)

select * from a;
 id | b_id | name
----+------+------
(0 rows)
```

But...

```
insert into b (name) values ('b test 2');
insert into a (b_id, name) values (2, 'a test 2');

delete from a;
DELETE 1
select * from a;
 id | b_id | name
----+------+------
(0 rows)

select * from b;
 id |   name
----+----------
  2 | b test 2
```

As you can see, b never got deleted, which is what i need to happen.

Comment: I, for one, would need some table structure, example data and trigger code.

Comment: @madflow done.  If you are wondering WHY I need the associated records to be deleted in both its because `a` is a join table in the actual application, so if they delete a record from either I need them to both be deleted.

Comment: I don't see any good reason to have a trigger on the master table `B`. Cascading a deletion is a native functionality of foreign keys. Regarding the slave table `A`, do records have a many-to-one relationship with `B`? About "*As you can see, b never got deleted, which is what i need to happen.*" -> the error message you get is...?

Answer (score 0):

As @Atmo pointed out, but using CASCADING deletes it takes care of the associated record.  I never knew about that!  Thank you.  That makes this so much easier and cleaner.